# UDP client is not reconnecting automatically

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I have a simple udp client/server program.

If the client is loosing the connection, or the server is restarting, the client won't reconnect automatically. I always have to restart the client manually.

This is my client-side socket config:

```
struct sockaddr_in si_other;
int s, i, j, slen=sizeof(si_other);
char buf[BUFLEN];
char message[BUFLEN] = "0";

if ( (s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
    die("socket");

memset((char *) &si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));
si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
si_other.sin_port = htons(PORT);
```

This is the main part of my infinite loop:

```
if (sendto(s, message, strlen(message) , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen)==-1)
    die("sendto()");

//clear buf
memset(buf,'\0', BUFLEN);

//try to receive some data, this is a blocking call
if (recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen) == -1)
    die("recvfrom()");
```

After doing some research I tried to change the socket mode to non-blocking by adding the following line:

```
fcntl(s, F_SETFL, fcntl(s, F_GETFL, 0 | O_NONBLOCK);
```

The client is now able to send one message to the server, but the client does not receive any answer. The error message is:

*recvfrom(): Resource temporarily unavailable*

Comment: UDP sockets don't establish connection at all

Comment: Is it about the `EGAIN` error? The `recvfrom()` operation would have *blocked*, but since the socket is *non-blocking* it returns immediately.

Comment: @bukkojot yes, sorry for a bad wording. the client is sending messages in an infinite loop. My target is that the client should continue sending messages when the server was not available for a few seconds.

Comment: Are you sure your server is successfully re-binding to the socket? If the server restarts without releasing the socket properly it will be unavailable for some time unless you force the bind (SO_REUSEADDR). The client is as you expect supposed to be a dump spam machine, sending UDP packets, so the problem is likely on your server...

Comment: @HansPetterTaugbølKragset The server does not showing up something like "address already in use".  Maybe this is a useful hint: Imagine I would want to start the client before the server. This does not work either.

Comment: @localhorst27 just to be sure, if you start the server then the client, then you get the packets to the server, but no replies back? And nothing else works to get communication?

Comment: I have a working communication between server and client. The only problem is the mentioned point when the server was restarted

Comment: it sounds very much like your server is not handling this correctly

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works properly:

Insert the following before the infinite loop:

```
struct timeval tv;

tv.tv_sec = 1;
tv.tv_usec = 0;
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*) &tv, sizeof(struct timeval));
```

As the function `die()` prints an error message and stops the program, I had to replace the following:

```
if (recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen) == -1)
    die("recvfrom()");
```

to

```
if (recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen) == -1)
    printf("no response from the server!");
```

`recvfrom()` is still a blocking call now, but only for 1 second. Previously it was a permanent blocking call, this was the only problem.